# Сравнение даты с сегодняшней датой

Tags: дата, sql

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сравнить дату с сегодняшней датой?

Comment: @Sergey4590, в зависимости от СУБД это будут разные функции, уточните какую используете Вы. Хотя, может быть есть и универсальное решение, о котором мне не известно

Comment: @Donil бд Firebird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Sergey4590](/users/8142/sergey4590), с `Firebird` не работал, но все прекрасно гуглится по запросу

> firebird date functions

И одной из первых ссылок мы видим функцию `DATEDIFF`, которая нам и нужна. Смотрим на описание и в низу странички видим примеры, из которых последний как раз то что Вам и нужно

`datediff (day from current_date to cast(? as date))`

Вместо `?` нужно подставить значение которое мы сравниваем с текущей датой. Функция вернет количество дней между текущей и переданной Вами

Comment: Короче говоря мне нужна была эта запись current_date

Answer (score 1):

Согласно стандарту текущую временную метку можно получить с помощью

```
current_timestamp
```